# How to set redis "session key prefix" using RedissonSessionManager

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, redis, redisson

I want to use "redisson-tomcat" library to store tomcat session in redis. But I need to add key prefix before storing sessions in redis. Is there any way to add session key prefix when storing sessions in redis ? As per my finding I need to configure "RedissonSessionManager" with tomcat. like bellow

`<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
          configPath="${catalina.base}/redisson.conf" readMode="MEMORY" updateMode="DEFAULT"/>`

it looks like lot of thinks can be configured using "redisson.conf" file but, I don't see any configuration to add key prefix.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like redison-tomcat currently don't have this feature, as a work around I extended `RedissonSessionManager` and overridden `getMap` method to set custom session key prefix [RedissonSessionManager::getMap](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson-tomcat/redisson-tomcat-6/src/main/java/org/redisson/tomcat/RedissonSessionManager.java#L133). I have also send them a pull request which includes this feature. If anyone is interested your can also have a look at the [pull request](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/pull/1321)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add keyprefix in your code.

```
<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
      configPath="${catalina.base}/redisson.conf" readMode="MEMORY" updateMode="DEFAULT" keyPrefix="yourPrefix" />
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: this "keyPrefix" feature is my contribution, have a look at my previous comment :)